# Transfer data with different type Primary key

Tags: sql-server

I'm redesigning very old DB where new tables have PK type `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` and old tables have `INT`.  There are also many relationships between tables. Can anyone help with how  not to lose any relationships and change PK type when transferring data?
Old Table:  Item(PK - itemID(int), FK - Vendor_Id(int), and Manufacture_Id(int) Manufacture ID is not as set FK but it should be in new table.

Comment: Please, be more specific. If you can post some data.

Comment: This is way too broad of a question, but you may want to create a temporary mapping table that houses the old and new primary keys for the transitioning purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have empty School and Student tables with `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` typed primary keys named id.
Let's say the relationship between students and schools is many-to-one, via a school_id foreign key.
The old tables are called oldSchool and oldStudent and have id columns of type `int`. oldStudent 
also has a foreign key named school_id.

Steps to take:

Extend all new tables that are referenced to by foreign keys with an extra column called old_id of type `int`. In the example table School would get this extra column:

```
ALTER TABLE School ADD old_id int;
```

All foreign key columns should get a sybling column of type `int`, called old_original_name. In our example 
Student should get an extra old_school_id column

Temporarily disable foreign key constraints:

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
```

Or, if that fails, drop all the foreign keys, to recreate them later, for example:

```
ALTER TABLE Student DROP FOREIGN KEY fk_school_id;
```

Also make those foreign key columns nullable:

```
ALTER TABLE Student MODIFY school_id int NULL;
```

Insert records from the old tables into the new tables, making sure the values of
primary keys and foreign keys are stored in the target's corresponding old_xxxxxx columns. 
In the example, it would look like this:

```
INSERT INTO School (old_id, name, address)
SELECT id, name, address
FROM   oldSchool;

INSERT INTO Student (name, class, old_school_id)
SELECT name, class, school_id
FROM   oldStudent;
```

Update the foreign key columns which are null by looking up the new id via the old_xxxx foreign key values. In our example:

```
UPDATE Student 
SET    school_id = (
    SELECT id
    FROM   School
    WHERE  old_id = Student.old_id);
```

Now make those foreign key columns not nullable again:

```
ALTER TABLE Student MODIFY school_id int NOT NULL;
```

Enable the foreign key constraints again.

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

Or if you had to drop them, recreate them, for example:

```
ALTER TABLE Student 
  ADD CONSTRAINT fk_school_id 
  FOREIGN KEY (school_id) 
  REFERENCES School(id);
```

Optionally drop all the old_xxxxx columns from all your tables. In the example:

```
ALTER TABLE Student DROP COLUMN old_school_id;
ALTER TABLE School DROP COLUMN old_id;
```

Optionally drop all old tables. In the example:

```
DROP TABLE oldStudent;
DROP TABLE oldSchool;
```

Done.